# How to I deploy Azure IoT Edge on Yocto on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi3, yocto, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to setup and learn Azure IoT Edge on Yocto running on a Raspberry Pi3.  Is there some documentation out there?

On Ubuntu 18.04, I tried the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure/meta-iotedge.git
git clone -b sumo git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-virtualization
git clone -b sumo git://github.com/meta-rust/meta-rust.git
git clone -b sumo git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
git clone -b sumo git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
git clone -b sumo git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi

cd ~/rpi 
source sources/poky/oe-init-build-env rpi-build


cd ~/rpi/rpi-build/
echo 'MACHINE = "raspberrypi3"' >> conf/local.conf
echo 'DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd virtualization"' >> conf/local.conf
```

modify ~/rpi/rpi-build/conf/bblayers.conf

```
# LAYER_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BSPDIR := "/home/ksaye/rpi/"

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-raspberrypi \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-iotedge \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-rust \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-virtualization \
  "
BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-iotedge \
"

cd ~/rpi
bitbake core-image-base


sudo dd if=~/rpi/rpi-build/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi3/rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi3.rpi-sdimg of=/dev/sde bs=4M
```

I can boot the SD Card, but no iotedge command or /etc/iotedge directory.

What am I missing?

I expected iotedge to be a command that runs or to see /etc/iotedge/config.yaml, but I did not.

Comment: You probably need to add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " iotedge-cli iotedge-daemon libiothsm-std"` in `local.conf` file to add those packages into your image.

Comment: can you please tell  full path of the local.conf

Comment: In my case, it was ~/rpi/rpi-build/conf/local.conf  I have a more up to date process here: https://kevinsaye.wordpress.com/2021/07/09/yocto-linux-running-the-long-term-support-version-of-azure-iot-edge/